# Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level (react)

Tags: reactjs, parsing

I'm using react and getting the following error with my code: "Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level"

I checked all my brackets and it looks like everything is right on that end. This error arose when I attempted to debug my constructor code by adding a class (tbh not sure if that's right
either). So not sure if the current parsing error is associated with that fix?

```
const Header = () => (
  <div className = 'header grid'>
    <h1 className="title">Jiffy</h1>
  </div>
)

// import React,  { useState } from 'react';
// function App() {
//   // Declare a new state variable, which we'll call "count"
//   const [props] = useState('');

class App {
  constructor() {
    constructor(props); {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        searchTerm: ''
      };
    }

    // with create react app we can write our methods
    // as arrow functions, menaing we don't need the constructor and bind 
    const handleChange = event => {
      const { value } = event.target;
      this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
        // we take our old props and spread them  out here
        ...prevState,
        // and then we overwrite the ones we  want after
        searchTerm: value
      }));
      if (value.length > 2) {
      }
    };


    const handleKeyPress = event => {
      const { value } = event.target;
      // when we have 2 or more characters in our search box
      // and we have also pressed enter, we thten want to run a search
      if (value.length > 2 && event.key === 'Enter') {
        alert(`search for ${value}`);
      }
    };

    // const searchTerm = this.state.searchTerm
    const { searchTerm } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="page">
        <Header />
        <div className='search grid'>
          
          <input
            className='input grid-item'
            placeholder='Type something'
            onChange={handleChange}
            onKeyPress={handleKeyPress}
            value={searchTerm} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );



    export default App;
  }
}
```

Comment: As the error suggests, the import statement should be before `const Header = () => (` statement.

Comment: And, your App class should be `class App extends React.Component {`.

Comment: And the export needs to be after the } brackets